# How Can I See the Logs of my Web Application Generated by Tomcat within IntelliJ

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ Idea, I can view certain tomcat specific logs except the one generated by my web application. For example, if I have an application named myWebApp, tomcat usually generates myWebApp.log under its log directory. How can I display this in IntelliJ Idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which loggin framework are you using? What is the `CATALINA_BASE` path?

Comment: I am using log4jsf. I have a CATALINA_HOME path instead of CATALINA_BASE, that is located in the root folder of my tomcat distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at "Edit Configurations... > Tab Logs" ? You can specify any log file to display in IDEA console.

[image]